# Azure devops release pipeline terraform local MacOS agent

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

set up Azure devops release pipeline from Github to release terraform to AWS

I have set up a release pipeline which consists of using my mac as an azure devops agent - this works fine

Set up Azure devops release pipeline to pull from Github - this works fine

Two tasks

- tf init
- tf plan

My init task is set up as below:

steps:
task:
ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV4@4 displayName: 'Terraform init '

inputs:
provider: aws

workingDirectory: '/Users/x/Documents/Learning/azure-devops-agent/vsts-agent-osx-x64-3.220.2/_work/'

backendServiceAWS: 'AWS-AZ-Pipelines'
backendAWSBucketName: local
backendAWSKey: terraform.tfstate

This works fine.

When I try to do terraform plan task I get error:

##[error]Error: There was an error when attempting to execute the process '/usr/local/bin/terraform'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/terraform ENOENT

I feel it is the configuration directory (working directory) causing the issue which looks as below:

/Users/x/Documents/Learning/azure-devops-agent/vsts-agent-osx-x64-3.220.2/_work/r1/a/_xgit_s3-testing/

In the directory above for the plan i can see main.tf file in there but i keep on getting the error

When i run terraform init and plan it works fine from the machine locally.

I am also able to see the path /usr/local/bin/terraform

any help appreciated